# Amazon Lex Lambda functions in C# - Documentation

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am trying to learn how to create Lambda functions for Amazon Lex in C#. Still I am having problem to find documentation for it.

For instance I can see that example function shown here: [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/bots-just-got-better-net-toolkit-lex-lambda-cognito/module-two/) , is using some classes and interfaces such as `LexEvent` or `IIntentProcessor`.

From Amazon documentation I just found expected input and output for these functions:

[Lambda Function Input Event and Response Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html)

[Order Flowers example review details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-bp-details-after-lambda.html)

or some high level details, non Amazon Lex specific:

[AWS Lambda function handler in C#](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html)

Still to write the code right now I'm just trying to debug example Amazon Lex Lambda function and understand how it works. Is there any documentation or tutorials that would make process of learning this less painful?